# Environment variables unavailable to jupyter notebook but I see them in base printenv

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I added a few environment variables to my activate script by adding

```
export MYVAR=blahblah
```

to the end.

When I activate via `source ./activate` and then do `printenv` I see them.

From a bash terminal if I launch python then do

```
import os
os.environ
```

then I see them.

BUT if I open a jupyter notebook either through the web interface or through VSC remote connection then I don't see them.

What's the missing link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the environment variables set in the activate script don't persist to a notebook session but I found that using kernel startups does what I need.

Specifically I used dot-env and the ipython kernel startup folder.

I made a 2 line script in `~/.ipython/profile_default/startup` which just says

```
fromdotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
```

and saved it as 00_make_envs.py in that folder

Also, I made an `.env` file in that same folder that has all the environment variables I want to use, it's in the same format that docker uses... ie

```
MYVAR1=blahblah
MYVAR2=foobar
```